# How can i download xml in javascript using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I know that in python, you can download xml data in script.

I am asking if JS can do the same thing.

like when i run "node downloadxml.js" it will do a "GET" to get the xml data and store it in a variable

just like doing

```
$.ajax({
    url: request_url,
    success: processData,
    dataType: 'xml'});
```

in browser

Comment: Are you wanting to do this in the command line? What would be your reason for having node download XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback

This allows you to make http requests to a server and process the received data